# File association using my executable jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have assigned an extension name for my files called *.XSCA. I would like to read the content of this file when the user click on it using my executable jar file to open it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you work under windows:

- create a batch-file (*.bat) that calls your jar (it should just be something like "java -jar yourJar.jar")
- click right on a file of your type, go to "Properties" and change the program that opens your file to that batch-file
- let the batch-file pass the file-location as an argument to your jar

You can write a batch-file with any text-editor. Use google to find out how. It will just be a wrapper for your jar that you can associate in windows with your file-extension-type.

EDIT:

OK, step by step:

That's your Java program (export it with Eclipse as a runnable jar):

```
public class ExtensionOpener {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.out.println("args:");

        for(String arg: args) 
            System.out.println(arg);

        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

That's the batch-file (just save it as e.g. **your-starter.bat**):

```
@echo run bat
java -jar C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\FileOpener.jar -file -%1
```

Now click right on your file (*your.fileextension*) and go to properties and associate it with the batch-file. That's it.

Comment: what I'm asking is how to make any associated file type open my program with the corresponding data. For example, if you have a .doc file it opens Microsoft word with whatever is saved to that file. I know how to associate the file extension to my program, but it just opens the program from the location of the file. How do I make the program read the file upon start-up?

Comment: try to pass the location of the file as an argument to your main-method.

Comment: how can i do that ? i am new in this