# How do I open a .jar when i double click on a file

Tags: java, jar, notepad

How do I open a .jar  when i click on a file.
So for example I made a notepad application in java and I want to assign all text files to open with my notepad program when I double click on it.

Comment: About which OS are we talking?

Comment: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9096991/file-association-in-mac)

Comment: @CommuSoft Windows 8

Comment: This should help: File association using my executable jar file


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579383/file-association-using-my-executable-jar-file

Comment: @KedarParikh it works thnxs